# What is attempt to apply non-function in r Matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

The Matrix

```
a<-matrix(c(2,3,-1)
          (0,-2,4)
          (0,-4,3),nrow = 3)
```

The Error

> Error in matrix((c(2, 3, -1)(0, -2, 4))(0, -4, 3)) :
> attempt to apply non-function

Comment: What is `c(2,3,-1) (0,-2,4) (0,-4,3)`? in your attempt?

Comment: to convert values into vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
> matrix(c(2, 3, -1, 0, -2, 4, 0, -4, 3), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3   -1
[2,]    0   -2    4
[3,]    0   -4    3
```